# 0509-036 0509-022 Cannot load module libclntsh.so

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, oracle12c, oracle-golden-gate

I'm running script remotly through JUnit and I'm receiving.

```
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program /u01/app/gg/ggsci because of the following errors:
    0509-150   Dependent module libclntsh.so could not be loaded.
    0509-022 Cannot load module libclntsh.so.
    0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
```

My script works great directly on machine. His body(lag_extract.sh):

```
cd /u01/app/gg
/u01/app/gg/ggsci << EOF
OBEY /u01/app/gg/lag_extract.txt
```

and my obey file (lag_extract.txt):

```
LAG EXTRACT *
```

- JSCH version: org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch-0.1.44_1.jar
- Oracle Golden Gate: 12.1.0.4.0

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was connected with lack of an system environments. Maybe it's a workaround, but I've just exporeted one missing system environment and now it works fine.

Comment: what missing system environment did you add?